# Typscript: Type 'Uint8Array' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]':

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on chrome extension project and have a problem parsing Uint8Array into String when I use 'typescript'(I tested same code without typescript and it occurs no errors).

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        requestListener,
        { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, ['requestBody']
);
```

```
function requestListener(details: any) {
            let id: number = details.requestId;
            let url: string = details.url;
            let method: string = details.method;
            let body: string = ''
            let headers: Header[] = [];
            if (details.method == "POST") {
                body = decodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,  new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes))); // <-- claims error
            }
          
        }
    }

}
```

Error message is..

```
var Uint8Array: Uint8ArrayConstructor
new (elements: Iterable<number>) => Uint8Array (+4 overloads)
A typed array of 8-bit unsigned integer values. The contents are initialized to 0. If the requested number of bytes could not be allocated an exception is raised.

Argument of type 'Uint8Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type 'Uint8Array' is missing the following properties from type 'number[]': pop, push, concat, shift, and 3 more.ts(2345)
```

Comment: I tried this in the Typescript playground and it seemed to compile: `String.fromCharCode.apply(null,  [...new Uint8Array()])`. I don't know if that works correctly for you but I think Typescript wants you to convert the Uint8Array to a normal array.

Comment: @cdimitroulas Thanks! Now it works like a charm! I would've selected an answer if you had posted an answer.

Comment: I'll add one so that you can do that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the `String.fromCharCode` function expects an array of numbers (`number[]`) as the argument, so you need to convert your `Uint8Array` into an array of numbers before passing it.

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(
  null,
  [...new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes)]
)
```

Comment: It does work without converting the array first, though. So I would save the operation and just add @ts-ignore

Comment: It would be great if the Typescript types for this function could be fixed so that none of this is needed